# counting in linq on join

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have two tables, site and customer. I want to count the number of customers registered with each site. I have join and I am returning counts with this:

```
var siteData = (
            from site in db.Site
            join cust in db.Customer on site.SiteID equals cust.SiteID
            group cust by site into g
            select new vm_SiteList
            {

                SiteName = g.Key.SiteName,
                Customers = g.Count()

            }).ToList();
```

My problem is those sites with 0 customers registered are not showing. Can someone tell me what I'm missing to include sites with 0 customers?

Comment: If you don't have customer, then you don't have SiteID, so you're not selecting those records and you can't count them

Comment: use a left join so sites is always listed: http://www.devcurry.com/2011/01/linq-left-join-example-in-c.html

Comment: check my answer

Comment: @Florian - yep, i understand the problem. i could have produced a solution in sql but linq is quite new to me. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. Insted of using join you can get count using let keyword. Also it will be faster then using join.

```
var siteData = (
                from site in db.Site
                let customerCount = db.Customer.Where(p=>p.SiteID == site.SiteID).Count()
                select new vm_SiteList
                {
                    SiteName = site.SiteName,
                    Customers = customerCount 
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: @Florian it will going to count all sites. You can try and check it. he wants to know number of customer with site.

Comment: i actually like this answer the best. it's the easiest for me to understand. thanks to all who took the time to respond.

Comment: If the where clause fails then it will return an empty sequence, ok, I missed that point. My bad, it is nice :)

Comment: By the way, on huge recordset, you should use join I think. I may be wrong but I think that .Where() use a cartesian product

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `Left Outer Join` by using `DefaultIfEmpty` method to get all the customers for which there are no sites.

```
var siteData = (
            from site in db.Site
            join cust in db.Customer on site.SiteID equals cust.SiteID
            group cust by site into g
            from subCust in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new vm_SiteList
            {

                SiteName = subCust?.Key.SiteName ?? string.Empty,
                Customers = g.Count()

            }).ToList();
```